# sstable2json error -- nonexistent keyspace

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I trying to debug tombstone issue on 2.1.14, when I run sstable2json  throws an error -- nonexistent keyspace: . this ks does exists in the database ..
any thoughts on debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0):

solved --- issue was related to meta-data; sstable2json was referring to previously dropped ks.